# PHP: How to get keyless URL parameters

Tags: php, url-parameters

I would like to get the parameter in a key such as http://link.com/?parameter

I read somewhere that the key is `NULL` and the value would be `parameter`.

I tried `$_GET[NULL]` but it didn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
if ($_GET[NULL] == "parameter") {
    echo 'Invoked parameter.';
} else {
    echo '..';
}
```

It just prints out `..` so that means I'm not doing it right. Can someone please show me the right way.

Comment: Try like `if ($_GET['parameter'] == NULL)`

Comment: $_GET superglobal is an array. When you do something like mypage.php?parameter you are adding a key to it without assigning a value. you will have $_GET = array("parameter" => ""). that's PHP 101

Comment: Before discussion answer me that can you create an array with empty key...???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no such things as keyless URL parameters in PHP. `?parameter` is the equivalent of `$_GET['parameter']` being set to an empty string.

Try doing `var_dump($_GET)` with a url like http://link.com/?parameter and see what you get.

It should look something like this:

`array (size=1)
  'parameter' => string '' (length=0)`

Thus, you can test it in a couple of ways depending on your application needs:

```
if (isset($_GET['parameter'])) {
   // do something
} else {
   // do something else
}
```

or

```
// Only recommended if you're 100% sure that 'parameter' will always be in the URL.
// Otherwise this will throw an undefined index error. isset() is a more reliable test.

if ($_GET['parameter'] === '') {
   // do something
} else {
   // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET` is a super global `assoc` array, that contains `parameter`=>`it's value` pairs. So, `parameter` is a key of the array.

For example, if your url is something like this: `myweb.com/?page=load&do=magic` than you `$_GET` is:

```
$_GET(
  [page] => load
  [do] => magic
)
```

If you want just to test, if `parameter` is in you URL as a param, you should do something like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['parameter'])
  echo "Here I am!";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the entire request_url like this

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

To get the part after `?`:

```
echo explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[1];
```

Comment: very bad solution. what if he will want to add another param to request?

Comment: @wingsofovnia, just offering a different way of doing it. might come in handy in certain situation :)

Answer (score 0):

You could via [`array_keys()`](https://www.php.net/array_keys):

```
$param = array_keys($_GET)[0];
```

Which would give you the name of the first querystring parameter, whether it has a value or not.

You could also get all of the parameters without a value like so:

```
$empty = [];
foreach($_GET as $key => $value)
    if(strlen($value) === 0) $empty[] = $key;

print_r($empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the part of the URL beginning with `?` with

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```